# In Landau's theorem, does the function have to tend to infinity in the abscissa?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I know Landau's theorem says that if we have a Dirichlet series with nonnegative coefficents with abscissa $a$, then it is impossible to find an analytic extension of our function which is defined also on $a$ and a neighborhood of $a$.

Does it follow that the Dirichlet series tends to infinity as $s$ tends to $a$?
I know that if we already had an analytic function defined on a neighborhood of $a$, then we can extend it to $a$ if the limit is bounded, but apriori why would we have that?

Thanks.

Comment: "As $s$ tends to $a$" through real values, or complex?

Comment: @DanielFischer real

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. Was confused yesterday.

Comment: @DanielFischer do you happen to have an answer? I feel bad not understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not follow that $f(s)$ tends to infinity as $s$ tends to $a$. It is possible that the series converges (absolutely) on the line $\operatorname{Re} s = a$.

As an example of such a situation, consider the series

$$f(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1 + \log n)^2\cdot n^s}.$$

Its abscissa of convergence is $1$, and the series converges absolutely on the line $\operatorname{Re} s = 1$, as can be seen for example using the integral test.